# Slow file upload to AWS cloud9 environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I've set up an AWS cloud 9 environment running on a t3.medium ec2 instance which is EBS optimized. The cloud9 environment is a no ingress environment that is accessed through AWS Systems Manager.

I am trying to use cloud9 as a test environment, and am uploading my local code and related files into the environment/instance.

There are about 65,000 files related to the program which I am trying to upload. All though there are many files, they are not particularly large. When I downloaded them from Git Lab, it only took about 2 minutes to download, however as I am trying to upload them into the environment it is on track to take about 4-5 hours. Is slow file uploading to cloud9 environments a known issue? And is there anything I can do to improve it?

Would I potentially see a significant upgrade by cloning the Git repository instead?

Comment: Try to clone, you cannot really loose with it, if it is only take 2 minutes in your local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to upload the desired files to S3 first, and then copy them into the instance running your cloud9 environment.

You can do this from the terminal within cloud9.